# Reset Sublime build system?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I installed sublime text on a new machine, the first time I went to compile java it asked me Ant/JavaC.

I accidentally clicked Ant, is there absolutely no way to change it? It doesn't look like it's in syntax-specific or normal settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change which build system is used from the Tools menu -> Build System when the Automatic one isn't suitable, or Tools menu -> Build With to choose a different variant.

ST tracks this in the session/workspace, rather than a user facing preferences file.